# Xcode - NSTimer firing at random intervals? No consistency

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nstimer

So I am using NSTimer to run a function every minute, it fires at the correct time for the first 3 or so attempts and then it suddenly starts firing every second. I have no idea why this is happening? Would anyone be able to let me know as to why NSTimer is firing inconsistently?

Here is the line where I have declared my timer.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0f target:self selector:@selector(checkForLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

It is worth noting that I have NSTimer declared inside of viewDidAppear.

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: @Prashant is probably right. Most likely you're creating more than one timer. Can you post more context of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a instance for `NSTimer` by declaring a property. Write a function which will initialize the timer and don’t forget to invalidate it before re-intializing it. Call `initializeMyTimer` in your `-viewDidAppear`.

```
-(void) initializeMyTimer 
{
    if(myTimer)
    {
        [myTimer invalidate];
        myTimer = nil;
    }

    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0f 
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(checkForLocation) 
                                             userInfo:nil 
                                              repeats:YES];

}
```

Comment: With this method my timer will only be called once, I need it to consistently be called whilst the application is open. Making the timer = nil will prevent it from firing every minute.

Comment: Declare the NSTimer property in AppDelegate.h and use it to call checkForLocation, start the timer once the application is started or wherver you want, you can stop/invalidate that timer to clear the system resources when the applicaiton goes into background in applicationDidEnterBackground and you can again start the timer in applicationDidEnterForground method in AppDelegate.m.